# Invalid request URI - Youtube API retrieve single user playlist

Tags: youtube

I am working on a client site. They have a series of playlist set up on there YouTube     account, which all load in to the video player depending on which page of the site the user     is on.

```
For example - 
homepage loads homepage playlist from his youtube account
culture loads the culutre playlist
and so on...
```

I had previously set up most of the playlists, and my client said they needed to set up     the rest of the playlists in their youtube account before I could add the rest. Well they     finally got around to creating the playlists, and told me to add them to the respective     pages.

Some of them work, and some dont. On the ones that do not I get an 'invalid request     URI' error. The ones that do, just load and work as expected. Both playlists were set up on     the same day, both are being called in the exact same way. Why would I be getting this     error? I can get the json response from each playlist, so I know the playlist url is     correct.

Site: http://www.Scrapple.tv

```
I'm sending a get request to this URL: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLAYLISTID?start-index=1&amp;max-results=50&amp;v=2&amp;format=5&amp;alt=jsonc

where PLAYLISTID is the id of the playlist that I am retreiving. The ones that my client has created today and work are on pages 'We The People' and 'Culture > Nitelife'.
```

Problem Pages:
Culture - Fashion 
Culture - People 
Culture - Music

Example of a working query:

```
  http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/HUp1agCRK5kDdqh-RwTBaMmk0Fo-_IeL?start-index=1&amp;max-results=50&amp;v=2&amp;format=5&amp;alt=jsonc

Example of non-working query:

    http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/HUp1agCRK5npY3kR8CQ9SLteral-krG2?start-index=1&amp;max-results=50&amp;v=2&amp;format=5&amp;alt=jsonc
```

Why would one be giving me an error of
'Invalid Request URI'

whereas the other, created on the same day, implemented the exact same way, is working.

Comment: It's very strange. I've created 5 playlists, two of them are able to display in the player, and the other three get an 'Invalid Request URI' error. 

Why would 2 work, and the other 3 not? All currently have 1 video in it for testing purposes. It just doesn't make sense. I tried to create a new playlist and use that URL but that didn't work either, spit out the URI error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow this is terribly embarassing but I have resolved the issue.

I was setting my $playlist_ID variables like this

```
$playlist_id == 'HUp1agCRK5mJYtUlx6IJqYxapBNBbmk7';
```

When the correct way is

```
$playlist_id = 'HUp1agCRK5mJYtUlx6IJqYxapBNBbmk7';
```

My equals operator was just wrong and the playlist ID was not being recognized.

Again, embarrassing that I just spent the past 3 hours resolving this, but glad it is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** For this request, you must provide an authorization token, which enables YouTube to verify that the user authorized access to the resource.

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/8BCDD04DE8F771B2?v=2

Comment: Yea I have had this all set up previously, and everything works. If you check the site more than half the playlists work on there respective pages. But all the playlists that I seem to be adding today are not working as the others are.

Almost as if the playlist structure has changed, or the API was updated again, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I actually added two today in the sections
We The People and Nitelife 

and they both seem to work no problem. I move on to People, or Fashion and implement them in the same way and then receive this error. But have done nothing differently